# Why does Krishna say he is the Ganga among rivers, when, as Parabrahman, he is ALL rivers?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/10/verse/31

> पवन: पवतामस्मि राम: शस्त्रभृतामहम् |
> झषाणां मकरश्चास्मि स्रोतसामस्मि जाह्नवी || 31||

> BG 10.31: Amongst purifiers, I am the wind, and amongst wielders of weapons, I am Lord Ram. Of water creatures, I am the crocodile, and of flowing rivers, I am the Ganges.

As Parabahman, he is the Ganga, he is all rivers, he is the ocean, he is the smallest rainwater puddle.

What was he trying to convey to Arjuna by presenting himself as "best of breed" in many categories?